# VF Page: Why does the cursor land on a specific custom date field by after page load?

Tags: visualforce, pageblocksection, apexinputfield

Does anyone know why the cursor always lands on the same field whenever the page is loaded or reloaded? I have other Visualforce pages and other fields on the record detail page but the cursor always lands on it.

Screenshot:

[image]

My VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Interview__c" sidebar="false" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" >
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">
                
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="background-color:#0E2D46"> <apex:outputText ></apex:outputText> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="width:100%;text-align:center;background-color:#0E2D46;color:white;padding:7px">
                    <apex:outputText > <b> Table Stakes </b></apex:outputText> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="background-color:#0E2D46"> <apex:outputText ></apex:outputText> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="vertical-align:middle;width:40%;text-align:center;background-color:#0E2D46;color:white">
                    <apex:outputText > <b> Candidate's Search Status </b></apex:outputText> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="width:40%;text-align:center">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Interview__c.Search_Status__c}"/> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="width:20%;text-align:center">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Interview__c.StatusLogDate__c}" /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <div align="center"> <apex:commandButton action="{!quicksave}" value="Save" /> </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard behavior. When a page loads, the Visualforce page finds an appropriate field to focus on based on tab indexes.

Resolution
To avoid the focus to shift to the input text field, the VF page code can be modified to have a simple Javascript code which would use the window.scrollTo function on the window.onload to shift the focus to the desired place.

For example, this is a sample code that can be used.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    };
</script>
```

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334695&type=1&mode=1